# Pipe Rust to an external Unix application

Tags: unix, rust

I want to send some data to an external Unix application from Rust. Say, I have some application like Unix's `wc`

```
let app = Command::new("wc").arg("-l").stdin(Stdio::piped()).spawn();
```

What I want to do is to send data from Rust to it, and then gather its Stdout. For example, I have the loop

```
for line in lines {
   app.<send data to it>(line);
}
```

Where I do not know what should I use in place of `<send data to it>`. I need to do it sequentially, that is, in a loop, using something like `lines.map(...)`, etc. I already browsed the docs of [`std::process::Command`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html) and [`std::process::Child`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html) and found that I could use `app.stdin.take().unwrap()`, but I'm not sure how exactly should I use it.

In the end, I want to gather the output of `wc`, i.e. the number of lines, or `lines.len()` in this case.

```
let output = app.wait_with_output()
```

If "lines" was a file, in this example Rust would behave like `cat` in `cat lines.txt | wc -l`  Notice that `wc` is just an example, it could be any other Unix application that allows for piping data to it.